# push to an array in a "then" clause but it's empty

Tags: firebase, promise

I'm adding some keys from a firebase database to an array, but it remains empty. The code is the following:

```
ref.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) { 
      snapshot.forEach(tag =>{
        tags1.push(tag.key);           
      })         
  });
```

I checked for the value of `tag.key` by printing it on the console inside the `forEach`, and all the keys are printed correctly.

Then, I've tried to perform a `forEach` on the `tags1` array, but it doesn't enter the `for`. I've printed the length of `tags1` and it is 0.

I've declared `tags1` this way:

```
let tags1 = [];
```

I've also tried to declare it as `Array<any>`, but it keeps staying empty.

Comment: The `tags1` array will not be populated outside the `then` clause. That is fundamental to the notion of asynchrony. This has nothing to do with typescript or ionic or firebase.

Comment: Did you mean "`.then(` *I've tried to perform a forEach on the tags1 array* `)`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go over the sequence in which things happen:

```
const tags1 = [];                     // 1 -- EMPTY

ref.once("value")                     // 2 -- EMPTY
    .then(function(snapshot) { 
      snapshot.forEach(tag => {
        tags1.push(tag.key);          // 4 -- GETS NEW VALUES        
      });
      console.log(tags1);             // 5 -- HAS ALL VALUES
  });

console.log(tags1);                   // 3 -- STILL EMPTY!
```